# Retornar datos de Javascript a controler con un método GET ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, controller, get

tengo una consulta con una webapp que estoy trabajando, tengo un método get que me trae información de una API, la información es llamada y pintada perfectamente, ahora bien, el api recibe 2 parámetros opcionales "page" y "pageSize" para la paginación, y esos se deben regresar en el mismo método get. Mi pregunta  es, utilizo AJAX para enviar la información de Javascript al Controller, ¿En un método GET, cómo devuelvo datos al controller y luego al service? se hacerlo con POST y UPDATE, pero para un GET no me funciona de la misma manera. Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Esta es la parte del javascript:

```
const GetByOwner = (callback) => {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `Client/GetByOwner?`,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        callback(response)
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

}

Y este el controller donde necesito recibir la información, específicamente en el método GetByOwner:

```
using Legal_WebApp.Models;
using Legal_WebApp.Services.Abstract;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Legal_WebApp.Controllers
{

[Authorize]
public class ClientController : Controller
{

    private readonly IClientService _clientService;
    public ClientController(IClientService clientService)
    {
        _clientService = clientService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByOwner()
    {
        var newPage = await _clientService.GetByOwner();
        return Ok(newPage);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateClients([FromBody] ClientModel client)
    {
        var newClient = await _clientService.CreateAsync(client);
        return Ok(newClient);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateClients([FromBody] ClientModel client)
    {
        await _clientService.UpdateAsync(client);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Puedes enviarlos por la query en la url.

```
 url: `Client/GetByOwner?page=3&pageSize=10`
```

Luego en el controller los puedes recuperar así:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByOwner([FromQuery(Name="page")] int page, [FromQuery(Name="pageSize")] int pageSize)
{
    var newPage = await _clientService.GetByOwner();
    return Ok(newPage);
}
```

Comment: Intenté hacerlo como lo colocaste, pero no trae ningún valor al controller, los parámetros retornan con valor de 0.

Comment: Edité la respuesta porque había que cambiar el nombre de un párametro en el controlador. La verdad es que no se como te llega el valor a 0, debería funcionar

Comment: Ya está resuelto, era porque el tipo de valor que devolvía era json en el AJAX, quité esa parte y funcionó